# Declaring an array of strings and integers

Tags: r

I have two csv file - one is a list of strings and other has both strings and floating values. If the strings in both the files match I need to copy the complete row from the second file to a temporary array. I have declared a matrix with n rows and m columns and saved is as dataframe `temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = m))`. I am using `for` loop to iterate over all rows and `strcmp` to compare the strings. But when the data is written to `temp` the strings are stored as integers. How should I declare this array? Is it possible to write this loop without declaring an array in R?

Comment: This question is unrelated to bioinformatics. You should ask somewhere more appropriate (e.g. stackoverflow). You might also want to add a minimal working example, it will be easier for other people to help you (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck !

Comment: I'm downvoting because this isn't really a bioinformatics question, but I suggest you take a look at `dplyr::semi_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` function of R might be useful. The function expects two data frames, with [optionally] columns to compare, and it will output all fields from both data frames where the comparison columns match.

```
> a <- data.frame(test=1:10);
> b <- data.frame(test=c(sample(1:10,5),sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"))),
                  output=rnorm(10));
> merge(a, b, by="test");
  test     output
1    1 -1.3800443
2    2  0.2934274
3    3  0.0868700
4    9  1.1766914
5   10  0.3793448
```

The `merge` function can be customised quite a bit (e.g. if you want NA set for non-matching rows), see `?merge` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you read in your two CSV files, you can explicitly declare the variable types for each column:

```
> a <- read.csv(..., colClasses=c("character"), ...)
> b <- read.csv(..., colClasses=c("character", "numeric", "numeric", ...), ...)
```

You could also investigate `as.is` or `stringsAsFactors`, although this can cause problems where there are duplicate strings. Using `colClasses` is more explicit.

Read the help documentation in `?read.csv` for a more complete explanation of these operators.

You can filter with the `%in%` operator in `match`:

```
> strings_of_interest <- as.vector(a$V1)
> b.filtered <- b[b$V1 %in% strings_of_interest,]
```

If I am reading your question correctly, perhaps you can then take `b.filtered` and turn that into the matrix you want.

Avoid use of `for` loops where you can. They can slow R down considerably. A good read on this subject is in the third chapter of Patrick Burns' [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvoting?

Comment: I think it is bad for a community when downvoting without any explanation. Please explain yourself.